# Saving large excel files issue

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

An excel file (about 90 MB) is a program with around 1300 Sheets with formulas and VBAs. As file is getting bigger, I have sometimes problem with saving it. It says: "Document not saved!" And I can't also save it to another location or name,  because Meni: "File" is not responding. I often lose many work that I did. I have 8GB of RAM memory. Is there something that can be done to increase stability or what else to solve my issue?

Comment: Are you using Office 64 bits?

Comment: Save As *Excel Binary Workbook (.xlsb)*. It will cut the size down substantially (depends upon type of data for exact proportions) and will decrease load and save time.

Comment: re: @DanielBonetti comment - [Choose the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261)

Comment: May I ask why you have 1300 sheets? Sounds like a nightmare to me.

Comment: I'll try to save as xlsb, But will My macros and vba work then?
Each sheet is representing one article and all traffic(inputs and outputs) are registered on that sheet. So, how much articles, that much sheets.

Comment: I suspect it would make your life much easier to use one data sheet with an additional column indicating the relevant article. Or a database. ;)

Comment: DataBase would be nice, but When I was makeing this program Year ago, I haven't had time and knowlage to do something like that. I would probably make it in MS Access.

Comment: I saved it as XLSB and got 55MB file from 90MB. All works fine, formulas, VBA-s, faster saving and openning file. Thank you all for your response, If we ever meet, I'll buy you a beer and a lap dance. One more thing: Can this xlsb work like shared workbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Save As-> Excel Binary Workbook.

[Spreadsheet1.com-Binary excel workbook](http://spreadsheet1.com/how-to-save-as-binary-excel-workbook.html)